# Javascript iterate over string looking for multiple character sets

Tags: javascript, regex, string, loops

Ok, so I know how to do a standard loop to iterate over a string to find a character or a word that matches a single character or word, but in this instance, I have multiple character sets that I am looking for.  Some are letters, some have characters (including protected ones).  I can't split it into an array of words on space or anything like that because the character sets might not have a space, so wouldn't split.  I suspect I'm going to have to do a regex, but I'm not sure how to set it up.  This is basically the pseudo code of what I'm trying to do and I'd appreciate any tips on how to move forward.  I apologize if this is an easy thing and I'm missing it, I'm still working on my javascript.

Pseudo code:

```
var string = "This *^! is abdf random&!# text to x*?ysearch for character sets";
var tempSet = [];

// start a typical for loop
for(string.length bla bla...){
  // look for one of those four character sets and if it hits one 
  if(foundSet == "abdf" | "x*?y" | "*^!" | "&!#")
    // push that character set to the tempSet array
    tempSet.push(foundSet);
    // continue searching for the next set until the string is done 

console.log(tempSet);  
//expected result = ["*^!", "abdf", "&!#", "x*?y"]
```

and all the sets are in the array in the order in which they appeared in the string

there is obviously more, but that part I can handle.  It's this line

```
if(??? == "abdf" | "x*?y" | "*^!" | "&!#")
```

that I don't know really how to tackle.  I suspect it should be some kind of regex but can you have a regex like that with a | when doing an if statement?  I've done them with a | when doing a map/replace but I've never used a regex in a loop.  I also don't know how to get it to search multiple characters at a time.  Some of the character sets are 3, some are 4 characters long.

I would appreciate any help or if you have a suggestion on how to approach this in an easier way, that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression. Just list all your strings as alternatives separated by `|`. Characters that have special meaning in regular expressions (e.g. `*`, `?`, `^`, `$`) will need to be escaped with `\` (you can safely escape any non-alphanumeric characters -- some will be redundant).

```js
var string = "This *^! is abdf random&!# text to x*?ysearch for character sets";
var tempSet = string.match(/abdf|x\*\?y|\*\^!|&!#/g);

console.log(tempSet);
```

If you need a loop you can call `RegExp.prototype.exec()` in a loop.

```js
var string = "This *^! is abdf random&!# text to x*?ysearch for character sets";
var regex = /abdf|x\*\?y|\*\^!|&!#/g;
var tempSet = [];
while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
  tempSet.push(match[0]);
}
console.log(tempSet);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great help. I have to keep it in a loop because other things need to be done based on what's found, but this regex gives me a starting point to work with.  thanks!

Comment: If you need a loop, take a look at the `RegExp.exec()` method to repeatedly execute the regexp and get the next match.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  Thanks so much for your excellent response!

Answer (score 2):

A bit more of a manual method than Barmar's excellent RegEx, but it was fun to put together and shows the pieces maybe a bit more clearly:

```js
var text = "This *^! is abdf random&!# text to x*?ysearch for character sets",
    detect = ["abdf", "x*?y", "*^!", "&!#"],
    haystack = '',
    found = [];

text.split('').forEach(function(letter){
    haystack += letter;
    detect.forEach(function(needle){
        if (haystack.indexOf(needle) !== -1
             && found.indexOf(needle) === -1) {
            found.push(needle);
        }
    });
});

console.log(found);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad I could provide you with some fun this evening. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the includes() function.

```
var sample = "This *^! is abdf random&!# text to x*?ysearch for character 
sets";
var toSearch = ["*^!", "abdf", "&!#", "x*?y"];
var tempSet = [];

for (var i = 0; i < toSearch.length; i++) {
    if (sample.includes(toSearch[i]){
        tempSet.push(toSearch[i]);
    }
}

console.log(tempSet);  
//expected result = ["*^!", "abdf", "&!#", "x*?y"]
```

This way you can iterate through an entire array of whatever strings you're searching for and push all matching elements to tempSet.

Note: This is **case sensitive**, so make sure you consider your check accordingly.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to play with this. I dropped it into jsfiddle and I'm getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" so I'll see if I can figure that out. :)

Comment: It's very possible I made a syntax error, hopefully that points you in the right direction though!

Answer (score 1):

I would just add this as a comment to Kevin's answer if I was able to, but if you need IE support you can also check searchString.indexOf(searchToken) !== -1.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf